# Cannot Read propery of undefined when trying to test a React Redux component with Jest

Tags: javascript, react-redux, jestjs

I am following the [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#components) on how to test components but I keep getting this error: [See image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSmip.png)

This is the test I have written:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
// Import your own reducer
import authReducer from '../../../reducers/auth';
import Login from '../Login';

function MyRender(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState,
    store = configureStore({ reducer: { user: authReducer }, preloadedState }),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}


test('fetches & receives a user after clicking the fetch user button', async () => {
  MyRender(<Login />);

  // should show no user initially, and not be fetching a user
  expect(screen.getByText(/Login/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

if you want to see my Login component you can check it here: [Login.js](https://github.com/Francesco-Manzoni/Social-Manzo/blob/main/client/src/components/auth/Login.js)

Comment: Can we see your reducer to see if everything is set up correctly? This undefined errors are very common when having a wrong setup, a typo, or something you missed.

Comment: This is the reducer https://github.com/Francesco-Manzoni/Social-Manzo/blob/main/client/src/reducers/auth.js

but I think the reducer is correct because the application is working correctly and the redux state is set correctly when i check it with redux devtools